# TypeScript doesn't seem to allow higher-order function argument generics

Tags: generics, typescript, higher-order-functions

I've run into a weird problem in my TypeScript code, which causes it to bail out of compilation with the following error:

`src/mutable_list.ts(47,25): 1005 ',' expected.`

The code I'm trying to compile is as follows:

```
44  export function flatMap<V,I,W,J>(
45    list: IMutableList<V,I>,
46    getFn: (V) => IList<W,J>,
47    setFn: (IList<W,J>) => V
48  ): IMutableList<W,J> {
49    return null;
50  }
```

It does work when I name the inner function argument of `setFn`, as follows:

```
47    setFn: (list: IList<W,J>) => V
```

I think that's pretty strange. I'm at a loss by why it specifically wouldn't work for generics arguments. I'd prefer not to have to name all my inner function arguments.

Can anyone figure out what the problem is here? Have I hit a bug in TypeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a syntax error here. Every argument in function type literals must still be named, e.g. you must say `(something: IList<W, J>) => V`.

If you just put the type there, it's treated as the argument name with implicit any type. In your case, an argument name cannot contain `<` so the parser failed.

Comment: Ah, so they _must_ be named. That does make sense. Thanks!